# Objective-C delegate notation

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have one question about Objective-C delegates. When I'm creating class with delegate my code looks like this:

```
@protocol MyDelegate
- (void)delegateMethod;
@end

@interface MyClass:NSObject {
    id <MyDelegate> delegate;
}
```

Could anybody answer me why is this <**MyDelegate**> in the line with instance variable declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the `delegate` variable (whatever it's actual type is), conforms to the `MyDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear whether MyClass above is supposed to be the delegate class, the user of the delegate, or an "innocent" 3rd party.

There is, of course, no need for the delegate object to store a pointer to itself.

The user (invoker) of the delegate generally needs to store the delegate pointer.  It could actually require you to create a subclass of some delegate class, and thus require you to pass a subclass of "MyDelegateClass".  In that case it would store a pointer to "MyDelegateClass".  But to allow you to combine your delegate with other functions in one of your classes (and to generally minimize the "tightness" of binding between the delegate's user and the delegate user's clients), the delegate is usually defined via a protocol rather than a class, and, in that case, Objective-C notation for an object of a given protocol is `id <TheProtocol>`.

The "innocent" 3rd party can accept and store whatever makes sense for its needs.  Presumably it "knows" about the user's intent (which the user of the delegate does not) and hence it may make more sense to store a "ClassOfThisApp" pointer.